# R: Convert a string to list object name for pheatmap annotation colors

Tags: r, pheatmap

I am trying to automate code for making pheatmap color annotations.
So that I do not have to personally annotate each sub sample.
However, I can't figure out how to convert the string from a  factor/ object name.
Is this possible?

I just receive an equal error, which I assume means I am equating a string to a string.

```
annotation_colors = list(
      Samples = c(Disease1 ="#0067f7", Disease2 = '#00fad5'),
      Vector = c(Pathology1="#3c00ff",  Control = '#00b3a7'))


annotation_colors = list(
      Samples = c(as.factor(unique(data$Samples[1])) = "#0067f7", 
as.factor(unique(data$Samples[2])) = '#00fad5')


Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:2:58: unexpected '='
1: annotation_colors = list(
2:           Samples = c(as.factor(unique(data$Samples[1])) =
```

answer derived from akrun advice:

```
     annotation_colors = list(
      Samples = c( setNames(c("#0067f7", '#00fad5'), unique(meta2$Samples))),
      Infection = c(setNames(c("#3c00ff", '#00b3a7'), unique(meta2$Infection))))
```

Comment: Use `setNames` to name.  The lhs of `=` doesn't evaluate the object. You can only pass a value literally.  i.e. use `list(Samples = setNames(c("#0067f7", '#00fad5'), unique(data$Samples[1:2])))`

Comment: Hi Akrun, Thanks so much your advice really helped!